# Get array key when using "withProgressBar" on Laravel Command Progress Bars

Tags: php, laravel

it is possible to get array key when using `$this->withProgressBar` on laravel command?

example :

```
$data = [
    0 => 'data1',
    1 => 'data2,
];

$this->withProgressBar($data, function ($value) {
    $this->storeData($value);
});
```

i want to pass array `$key` on `$this->storeData($value)` become like `$this->storeData($key, $value)`

Comment: i don't see a way to do that unless you want to override the `withProgressBar` method itself ... you have access to the `ProgressBar` instance as the second argument in this case, but not the current key of the iterable, `$data` .... you could adjust your `$data` array's values to be arrays themselves though, then `$value` would be an array so you could hold an identifier for the key and the value

Comment: @lagbox thanks for the advice. In the end I chose to use manual control as in the documentation